# Understanding Vinayaka Chaviti pooja

Tags: ganesha

Every year I perform `Vinayaka Chaviti Pooja (Ganesh Chaturthi)`, I always wanted to understand the mantras or words we use in pooja. I searched over the internet but did not get any results. I am looking for a source where I can understand the mantras of this pooja.

I am adding the pooja details here for reference:

[In Telugu language.](https://bhaktinidhi.com/vinayaka-chavithi-pooja-vidhanam/)
[In English language.](https://hindupad.com/ganesh-chaturthi-puja-procedure-with-mantras-stotrams-vrat-katha-or-story/), [another one](http://hindusphere.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Vinayaka-chavithi-vrathakalpam-in-English.pdf)

Comment: can you put those mantras as well?

Comment: @indiPy, I have added links to my post.